# CSOM query certain date

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query

I have a list that has an end date in. Is there anyway to filter out the dates that are passed todays date?

```
function retrieveCurrentListProperties() {
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Urgent Alerts");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var q =  "<Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='End Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'><Today /></Value></Leq></Where></Query>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
    this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Id)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCListItemsLoadSuccess), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onCListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

    var listEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();
    //iterate though all of the items

count = this.listItems.get_count();
var cAlerts = document.getElementById('cAlerts');
cAlerts.innerHTML = 'Total Alerts : ' +count;
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<Today />` tag for comparing current date.Below is the code:

```
var q = "<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='Start Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'><Today /></Value></Leq></Where>";
```